# node js, 30% игроков не могут подключится

Tags: javascript, node.js

Серверная часть игры на node js, при входе в игру флешка сначала ждет ответа от сервера и лишь потом игра запускается. Третей части игроков так и не удается подключится к серверу по неизвестным причинам. Есть подозрения, что это как-то связано с номером порта, так как допрашивал игрока у которого не запускалась игра и когда я сменил порт на ноде, то у него все-таки зашло в игру. Что делать? В какую сторону копать? Mожет можно слушать несколько портов или еще какие выходы могут быть? Запускал на порте 6969, потом сменил на 6868.

Comment: Могут быть ограничения самой ОС на ко-во одновременных соеденений

Comment: сколько пользователей подключенны одновременно и какая ось?

Answer (score 1):

По какому протоколу реализована связь? в случае с WS могут быть проблемы у клиентов с прокси (https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#wss), в этом случае нужно шифровать трафик.